# Autocomplete Regular Expression Filtering

Tags: c#, ajax, regex, jquery-ui-autocomplete, webmethod

I'm developing a textbox with autocomplete capabilities using jquery-ui-autocomplete. And I'm having trouble getting it to function like I want it to. To start off I have a table of company with some of the column values being abbreviated ex.) A.B.C. Corp.. Everything with this autocomplete works except for the desired functionality that when you type: abc corp or ABC corp it'll match with A.B.C. Corp, but it doesn't :( it only matches if you type a.b.c. corp. Here is my code so far:
And Im not entirely sure how to go about it.
Any tip in the right direction is very much appreciated.
how could i match abc corp to A.B.C. Corp.?
my current way doesn't work

```
Regex.Match(hint, "/([A-Za-z\\.])/g"
```

Thanks
**client side:**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="customerSearch"></asp:TextBox>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MainContent_customerSearch").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $("#MainContent_customerSearch").on("change keyup", function () {
                        var hint = { hint: $("#MainContent_customerSearch").val() };
                        //call webmethod
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Default.aspx/getProducts",
                            data: JSON.stringify(hint),
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        }).success(function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Description,
                                    value: item.Description
                                }
                            }));
                        }).error(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    });
                },
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 1,
                autoFocus: true

            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**server side:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }


        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static List<Product> getProducts(string hint)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            using (var db = new AppDB())
            {
                try
                {
                    products = db.Products.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(hint)).ToList();
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
            return products;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to ignore the special chars in your company name

Add a private helper method to `_Default` class

```
private string RemoveSpecialChars(string @string)
{
    return @string.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, c) => s.Append(c)).ToString();
}
```

then Change your `WebMethod` like so

```
public static List<Product> getProducts(string hint)
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    using (var db = new AppDB())
    {
        try
        {
            products = db.Products.Where(p => RemoveSpecialChars(p.Description).Contains(RemoveSpecialChars(hint))).ToList();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    return products;
}
```